# What is the best technology to migrate Oracle Forms and Reports to

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-adf, oracleforms, oraclereports

When migrating Oracle Forms and Reports, there are several options for that :

1. ADF
2. APEX
3. Yor suggestion ...

Which one do you think is the best in terms of business continuity and also ease of technological transition? Do you have experience in such migrations?

At the end, I would like to know if it would be necessary to migrate or just keep "Oracle Forms/Reports"

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of what tool vendors might say, this is going to be an exercise in rewriting your application.

So the real questions is, why do you want to do this?  Oracle are continuing to support Forms for some time yet.  There are plenty of things we can do to modernize our Forms applications whilst retaining our investment in the existing software.  I urge you to look at Mia Urman's presentation [Give Your Forms a Facelift: Tips and Tricks for Forms UI Modernization](http://oracleformsinfo.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/presentations-from-ukoug-development-sig-meeting-forms-in-the-21st-century/) which she gave at a UKOUG event I helped organise a couple of years ago.

If your mind is absolutely set on a re-write you'll find APEX is the easiest path for developers with a Forms/ PL/SQL background.

---

Update for 2018:

Oracle have been getting back behind Forms. The 12c release had over 100 new features. Okay, some are quite minor but it's a clear statement of intent. [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/documentation/oracleforms-12210-newfeatures-2906037.pdf).

Comment: Because the App is not really well done in the first time...Then I'm looking arround to find an alternative solution such as ADF, APEX or maybe keep forms and modernize it. But to invest in something might be durable because forms is near to end i guess

Comment: take a look at this page I maintain for my students. Might be helpful. https://sites.google.com/site/joeztechland/adf-links/forms2adf. While true, Oracle will support Forms for a while to come, it is not receiving all the new features and such that ADF is. I would suggest looking at ADF.

Answer (score 1):

It's a big "it depends". ADF is a comparable alternative, while APEX is easier to learn and find resources to build.

The developer tools statement of direction is a great place to start and a while ago I provided my own commentary (http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2012/03/on-oracles-statement-of-direction-for.html)

Answer (score 1):

i think you should also check [oracle JHeadStart](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jheadstart/overview/index.html) , as mentioned in the documentation :

> JHeadstart Forms2ADF Generator; creates ADF Business Components and a
>   JHeadstart Application Definition file based on Oracle Forms files

Hope that Helps .